# Bind to an App property in a different project

Tags: c#, wpf

This is a WPF question. I have two projects in my solution, say ProjectA and ProjectB, with ProjectB referencing ProjectA. In ProjectA App.cs class, I've declared a property PropA (public and static). My problem is this: how can I bind to PropA from XAML in ProjectB?

Obviously

```
{Binding PropA,Source={x:Static Application.Current}}
```

won't work, and I can't wrap my head around the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

To clarify any confusion, here are some details.
ProjectA contains a ViewModel class that needs to update an App level collection. My problem was binding to the collection in XAML from a window in ProjectB. I finally solved this by moving the collection to ProjectB App class and firing an event from the ViewModel in ProjectA. Then, in the code-behind of the window (where I set an instance of the ViewModel as data context) I simply subscribe to the event and act accordingly. MVVM purists might turn green now, but a little code-behind never hurts!

Comment: Ok, so you referenced ProjectA, but did you create an instance of ProjectA.App? A binding requires a source object.

Comment: Yes, the instance is created just fine.

Comment: If you've created an instance, you just need to reference that instance in your binding. See my answer.

Comment: Are you trying to share the actual bound data between both applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot. you would need a vise versa reference and this circular reference is invalid to C#.

You can extract this to a third project and have the other two use it.

Comment: I thought so! :( I guess I'll have to use another project - or think of a way to go around the problem

Comment: ProjectA requires no reference to ProjectB here.

Answer (score 0):

You somehow need a reference to a `ProjectA.App` instance. For example, you can have a public property on your `ProjectB.App`:

```
namespace ProjectB 
{
    public partial class App : Application 
    {
        ...

        // this public property exposes an instance of ProjectA.App
        public ProjectA.App TheOtherApp ...

        ...
    }
}
```

Then you have bind to it like:

```
{Binding TheOtherApp.PropA, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}
```

Comment: @GeysserSdz oops, my binding example was wrong, just corrected.